# linux script result getting using php (executable)

Tags: php

I want to run a script which will return hostname and then I want to display that hostname using php. This thing I want in exe format so that i can run that exe and will come to know the hostname of perticular pc. Is it possible.

```
CPU details :
<div style="display:block;" id="uip"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $a = GetHostByName($REMOTE_ADDR);?>" /></div>
<div style="display:block;" id="uip"><input type="text" value="<?php echo gethostbyaddr('127.0.0.1');?>" /></div>
```

Comment: Show some effort you have done for that.

Comment: Um, [`gethostname`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostname.php)?

Comment: exe format?.... you mean you want to compile a PHP script to a Windows(?) executable?

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan Now if you can check for that

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
echo gethostname()."\n";
?>
```